# Select lists only change in Chrome

Tags: javascript, list

I have 2 select lists that display the correct dropdown selection in Chrome,but it doesn't display properly in IE or Firefox (it shows Beagle and Persian for both dog and cat).

```
  <label for="typeofpet">Type of Pet</label>
    <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Dog</option>
    <option value="2">Cat</option>
    </select>

    <label for="typeofbreed">Type of Breed</label>
    <select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="1">Beagle</option>
    <option value="2">Persian</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select1').change(function() {
    var $id = $(this).val();
    var selectfirst = false;

    $('#select2 option').each(function() {
      if($(this).val() != $id) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        if(selectfirst == false) {
          selectfirst = true;
          $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
 });
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Thank you!
Faith

Comment: Make sure you are removing the 'selected' attribute from all other options so there isn't a conflict.

Comment: Firefox and IE do not respect `hide()` (`style="display:none"`) on `<option>` elements. You'll have todo this a different way. Easiest would probably just to have two different breed `<select>`s one for cats and one for dogs and then show/hide those.

Comment: @Jack or delete and re-add option elements I guess..

Comment: hiding of options don't have cross browser support... instead you should add/remove the valid elements